# Which symfony-based CMS is the most extensible?

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, diem-cms

I'm looking for a symfony-based CMS, and I have heard about Diem and Apostrophe, but none of them offers all of the features I am searching for.

In your opinion, which of these CMS' is the most easy to extend? Do you know any other Symfony-based CMS I would want to consider?

EDIT : By 'to extend' I mean adding probably unsupported features, like Pdf rendering, adding menu from another sf application, content creation through web services... and all sort of special stuff my client would want.

Comment: You may want to define your requirements a bit more in terms of "extending" the CMS - what are you after specifically? Also, add Sympal to your list...

Comment: I'm not considering Sympal because of what you can read on their homepage : "Sympal is not currently being actively developed. For more information on this or standalone plugins created from Sympal, read here. If you're looking for a stable CMS built with symfony 1.x, check out Diem or Apostrophe Now" I'm going to edit my post regarding the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Diem and Apostrophe will allow you to extend quite easily.

It is just a matter of selecting the base that best suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophe already has many of those features.  Check out Apostrophe engines.